# Image cropping without knowing x and y c#

Tags: c#, image

ive done some searching online I cant find a solution for my problem.

I have various tiff image files, they all have white backgrounds and contain a small image

example tiff image size is 2700 x 3500, the small image is located at 200,200 and is 300x300

I need to crop this part of the image out, now this is easy but I have many tiff images and the small image that is contained in the tiff may be at different places and be of different sizes.

I did try going through every pixel, finding the first instance of a pixel that wasn't white, scanning down to the bottom of the page, then scanning along, its a very heavy process and I had mixed results, mostly because I was looking for white pixels and sometimes the image contained in the tiff had a white part.

Im unsure how to approach this problem and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Scan a line/column and if it's the same color - delete it. This should eliminate any border at the end.

Comment: can I remove lines and columns within a bitmap? if I can then that could be a solution.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556447/whats-an-efficient-eway-to-tell-if-a-bitmap-is-entirely-black) for an example of "locking" the bitmap which lets you read pixel data more quickly, if you're not doing that already.

Comment: You don't necessary have to *delete*. You can find your `x` and `y` and then use @King solution to crop (if it works).

Comment: This reads as "write an algorithm for me". Your problem isn't the C# code, it's defining an algorithm. Surely _you_ can think of a more efficient way to find non-white pixels? Do you _have_ to check each pixel, or can you do a "binary search"? Like start in the center, then test pixels between the borders and the center, then the pixels between those, and so on.

Comment: Yes codemaster is was a bit of a "what algorithm should I use" I already had an algo that from top to bottom of the image found the first non white pixel, that gave me the x,y of the top left this returned as I don't need to scan the rest of the image, I then had another function that from the bottom right of the image scanned up and left for the first non white pixel, it was all a bit of a mess. Im unsure what you mean about going from the centre, the small image contained within the bigger tiff could be anywhere.

Comment: @CodeCaster After thinking about it for a while I couldn't figure out how to write binary search in this case. To be specific, I'm not sure how to reduce search interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did try going through every pixel, finding the first instance of a pixel that wasn't white, scanning down to the bottom of the page, then scanning along, its a very heavy process and I had mixed results, mostly because I was looking for white pixels and sometimes the image contained in the tiff had a white part.

You didn't post your code, so I can't be sure what algorithm you're using now, but one loop through every pixel is enough to find image on white background.

Sample code:

```
int minX, minY, maxX, maxY;

minX = (int) image.Width;
minY = (int) image.Height;
maxX = maxY = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
    {
        var color = GetPixelColor(image, x, y);
        if(color!=Colors.White)
        {
            minX = Math.Min(minX, x);
            maxX = Math.Max(maxX, x);
            minY = Math.Min(minY, y);
            maxY = Math.Max(maxY, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Here:

- `minX` - X coordinate of the topmost non-white pixel;
- `minY` - Y coordinate of the leftmost non-white pixel;
- `maxX` - X coordinate of the lowermost non-white pixel;
- `maxY` - Y coordinate of the rightmost non-white pixel.

Required image is from `(minX, minY)` to `(maxX, maxY)`.

Nested loops require `Width * Height` steps to complete. You need to implement `GetPixelColor` method to check the pixel by coordinates. Performance of the algorithm mostly depends on an implementation of `GetPixelColor`. If you'll store pixel colors in array this algorithm should be efficient enough for most purposes.

Comment: @CodeCaster from the OP's description it seems she/he is doing something unnecessary (triple nested loops or something). `10^6` operations shouldn't take a lot of time.

Comment: hey default locale, thanks for that, I had just coded something up similar but had used get pixel and needed two functions both returning a point, the good thing was that it returned as soon as it found a non white pixel, the bigger the image the quicker it returned. your implementation is by far much better, although it still goes through every pixel, thanks a lot.